# REQUEST_URI ou REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING?

Tags: php, apache, url-amigável

Bom, estou fazendo uma classe de url amigável e no arquivo `CONFIG.PHP` eu dei um define no seguinte

```
define('UA',explode('/',$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']??null));
```

Porem quando digito o arquivo existente, por exemplo `('teste.com/produto/iphone-7-64gb/35')` ***o arquivo produto existe***. Quando dou o var_dump ele me retorna um array com uma string vazia, porem se eu uso esse metodo:

```
define('UA',explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']??null));
```

Ele me retorna vários arrays com os posicionamentos certo, mas no índice `UA[0]` ele me retorna uma string vazia. Queria uma solução, pois no vídeo aula que estou assistindo o método `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING funcionou perfeitamente.

.Htaccess

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?$1
```

Comment: REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING é gerado exclusivamente pelo .htaccess e só irá obter o querystring, REQUEST_URI irá obter a URL+querystring. Vale notar que o REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING é algo que vai sendo gerado a cada redirecionamento interno (da reescrita), então pode gerar algo como `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` e depois `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING`, dependendo de quantos redirecionamento ocorrerem. O ideal é você postar o seu HTACCESS para entendermos o que fez e o que precisa de fato para podermos até oferecer uma solução mais organizada.

Comment: postei o htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` é gerado exclusivamente pelo `.htaccess` e só irá obter o querystring, `REQUEST_URI` irá obter a URL+querystring.

Vale notar que o `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` é algo que vai sendo gerado a cada redirecionamento interno (da reescrita), então pode gerar algo como `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` e depois `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING`, dependendo de quantos redirecionamento ocorrerem.

O que você pode fazer para facilitar é simplesmente passar como um parametros GET, assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?PATH=$1 [L]
```

E no PHP pegaria assim (php7):

```
define('UA', explode('/', $_GET['PATH'] ?? ''));
```

Em php5:

```
define('UA', explode('/', empty($_GET['PATH']) ? '' : $_GET['PATH']));
```

### PHP_SELF

Outra maneira para evitar o controle do parametro `PATH` seria usar o `PHP_SELF` combinado com `parse_url`, primeiramente o HTACCESS deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Então o PHP deve ficar assim:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PHP_URL_PATH); //isto irá remover a querystring do sufixo

define('UA', explode('/', $path));
```

É claro que `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, mas creio que PATH_INFO não seja *standard* e talvez possa variar (vir a não funcionar) dependendo da versão do Apache, neste caso prefiro recomendo que use mesmo `PHP_SELF` combinado com `parse_url`.

No caso o resultado do `UA` para `teste.com/produto/iphone-7-64gb/35` será algo como:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => produto
    [2] => iphone-7-64gb
    [3] => 35
)
```

Note que o `[0]` ficou vazio, isto porque o PATH de uma URL sempre começa com `/`, então para evitá-lo você pode simplesmente usar `ltrim` ou `substr`, por exemplo:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PHP_URL_PATH); //isto irá remover a querystring do sufixo

define('UA', explode('/', ltrim($path, '/')));
```

Comment: Ahhh obrigado amigo!! Ficou muito mais claro agora!! nota 100000